# Bootstrap 4.1 JS components - not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4.1 Components that require javascript do not appear to be working when using the quick start template.

For example: 
- tooltip
- popover

Here is a plunk with the code.
It is using the quickstart template from bootstrap.com ( BS 4.1 )

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/uoW5CalhBbvJ4v3h4aN5?p=preview&preview

Answer (score 0):

As [stated in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/)...

> Popovers (and Tooltips) are opt-in for performance reasons, **so you
>   must initialize them yourself**.

```
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/J025HzRcTx

Comment: The Bootstrap styles work fine in Angular.  However, I can't get the JS/JQuery to work e.g., tooltips, popovers, scrollspy etc..    
I don't see/ can't find docs on how in integrate these types of components in to angular ( https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/javascript/ )   I do see   https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home   However, are there any comprehensive docs on just using BS 4.1?

Comment: That's outside the scope of the question.